# CSS for element SELECT multiple=yes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to be able to define a height for the select element when its multiple to false

```
select{height: 30px;}
```

But I don't want it to be applied when the select has the multiple=yes.

Can it be defined in CSS?

Comment: select[multiple=true]{ /* style */ }

Answer (score 79, accepted):

First things first, in order for a `select` element to *not* be in multi-selection mode, the `multiple` attribute must be *entirely omitted*. Even if you set `multiple="no"` or `multiple="false"`, the standard behavior is the same as HTML `multiple` or XHTML `multiple="multiple"`. For more information, refer to [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html).

With this in mind, use the CSS3 `:not()` selector to exclude any `select` with that attribute:

```
select:not([multiple]) {
    height: 30px;
}
```

Or if you need IE7+ support, apply the height to all `select` elements then reset it for those with that attribute:

```
select {
    height: 30px;
}

select[multiple] {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select[multiple]{
height: 30px
}

select[multiple]:focus{
height:auto
}
```

I don´t know if this answers the question. It´s a contribution.